# How can you open/view .eml files in Outlook 2007 (no regedit permissions)?

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2007

For those of us in a corporate environment who have no control over what email client to use, the [suggested fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/956693/files-that-have-the-eml-file-name-extension-do-not-open-in-outlook-200) from Microsoft (and [many](https://zonalivre.org/2009/10/15/how-to-open-a-eml-file-in-outlook-2007/) [other](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/open-eml-files-in-outlook/) [sources](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/354)) on opening .eml files in Outlook 2007 doesn't help, since we typically don't have registry access and can't download add-ins.

One solution buried in the myriad frustrated forum users' posts is to use the "Run" application with the following construction:

```
"[path to outlook]\Outlook.exe" /eml "[path to eml file]\[Filename].eml"
```

Is it possible to embed this inside a macro that can be accessed from (for example) Outlook itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will work when run from inside Outlook 07; it prompts for a .eml file and then opens it using a shell command in the form of the "Run" prompt in the question. Unfortunately because of Microsoft's 'unique' support for VBA objects, it's not possible to call `FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)` from inside Outlook.

As a result, the below calls an instance of Excel to handle the dialog box. The `Application.Visible = True` line ensures the dialog box is brought to the front, as it can open behind the current application depending on the window environment.

You may need to edit `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\Outlook.exe` to reflect the installation location of your copy of Outlook.

```
Sub OpenEML()
'   Macro to open EML type outlook files
    Dim otherObject
    Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
    Set otherObject = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set fDialog = otherObject.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Open"
        .Title = "Select an EML file"
        'Allow only eml selection
        .Filters.Add "EML", "*.eml", 1
        otherObject.Application.Visible = True
        .Show
        otherObject.Application.Visible = False
        'If some items are selected...
        If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
            fileNm = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing selected"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    Dim appNm As String
    appNm = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\Outlook.exe"
    Dim retval
    'MsgBox """" & appNm & """"
    retval = Shell("""" & appNm & """" & " /eml " & """" & fileNm & """", vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```